# BigQuery query to mimic User Explorer export

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

In Analytics under "User Explorer" it is possible to export a single users sessions as "user-report-export.json".

Google has made an analytics sample dataset available in BigQuery (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089). Is it possible to create a query to output a similar format as the "User Explorer" report to enable exporting all my users in one large .json file instead of having to export the files one by one?